# How many hours/week on the ISS is spent on science vs maintenance?

Tags: iss, crewed-spaceflight

This was asked in 2016 : [Does ISS crew exercise time count toward their X hour work week?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/17286/does-iss-crew-exercise-time-count-toward-their-x-hour-work-week) The answer as of 2016 was 40 hours / week for a crew of 6.
But as noted there, when the crew size increases to 7 there would be a significant increase in science output.
With crew dragon carrying an extra crew number, is there an updated figure for this number?

Comment: Reminds me of this one: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/8285/how-many-man-hours-are-spent-on-international-space-stations-maintenance?rq=1

Comment: From [another answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/24383/16780): "*The staff on board [get a single person-day of science work completed] when there are 6 astronauts, between exercise, sleeping, and maintenance*" (reformatted sentence for clarity). This seems weird/extreme. Assuming 8 hours of sleep, 6 hours for relaxation/personal hygiene/etc., so that you have (24-8-6=)10 hours of work per day: at 6 persons = 60 working hours per day, you would get only 8 hours **(13%) for science, and the rest is all chores/maintenance**. I'm a bit doubtful but I know nothing.

Answer (score 4):

On Expedition 55 in 2018, POIC (Payloads Operations Integration Center) at MSFC set a record of 109.25 payload hours in a week, split between 4 USOS crew members.

I worked at POIC during that time period as a flight controller. Unfortunately I don't have average numbers before/after, but that's the number that sticks in my head because we had a live video crew conference to celebrate.

When ISS was being assembled, payload ops were few and far between. Recent years have skewed more heavily toward payload hours though, since systems maintenance tasks don't require as much crew time as assembly did.